# Javascript If statement not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

My math all seems correct, the only thing that's not working is the if statement. It always does the math off of the male value.

the javascript:

```
function updatespending() {
    var age = parseFloat(document.forms[0].CurrentAge.value);
    var value = parseFloat(document.forms[0].NetWorth.value);

    if(document.forms[0].sex.value = "male") {
        var yearsleft = Math.round (76 - age);
    } else if(document.forms[0].sex.value = "female") {
        var yearsleft = 81 - age;
    }
}
```

the html:

```
<table width="433" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td class="liquidate">How much will you have to live off of if you liquidate all of your assets?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="381" height="68">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Sex:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Current Age:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" onchange="updatespending()" onkeyup="numericOnly(this)" maxlength="2" size="3" value="0" name="CurrentAge" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" >Annual Spending Available:</td>
                    <td>$<input name="AnnualSpending" disabled="disabled" readonly /> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would also like to make it so that if the individual changes the sex from male to female that it would updatespending as it does when I update the current age. Not so sure that a on change would work correctly. Any other suggestions would be great.

Comment: you are using an assignment operator `=` instead of a comparison one `==`

Comment: I wonder why you think the assignment operator `=` does different things in different contexts.

Answer (score 7):

Problem is you are saying

```
if(document.forms[0].sex.value = "male")
//this statement always return true so it will always go to if statement block.
```

You should say

```
if(document.forms[0].sex.value == "male") {
```

Comment: in updating the if statement, to ==, text box for the annual spending is no longer updated when updating the age.

Comment: @WesleyKluckhohn That's because there's nothing in your JavaScript that even attempts to modify the annual spending text box...

Comment: @gnack I had forgot to add this in there

document.forms[0].AnnualSpending.value = Math.roung (value / yearsleft);

Answer (score 0):

Your are using only one equal, always remember... a single equal is assignment of value, and will almost always return true, double equals is a comparison, and triple equals a type strict comparison.

That being said, try changing it to:

```
if(document.forms[0].sex.value == "male") {
   var yearsleft = Math.round (76 - age);
} else if(document.forms[0].sex.value == "female") {
   var yearsleft = 81 - age;
}
```

Let us know if that helps.

Comment: `a single equal is assignment of value, and will return true`, oops. It will return the value assigned, which is then type converted to true or false.

Answer (score -2):

I see some errors.

1. the input radio is not closed. It should be like

   ```
   <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male"></input>
   ```
2. You did not provide a default value for the radio. So after the page is loaded, NO value is checked. As a result, the document.forms[0].sex.value is neither male nor female. Please add a default value and try again:

   ```
   <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked="checked">Male</input>
   <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female</input>
   ```
3. the = should be == , in the if statement.

Comment: This is incorrect, the input tag is a void element and thus has no accompanying closing tag.

Comment: I wasn't the person who voted this down, but I suspect I know why that person did. The third point is the only truth here. The first one is acceptable in HTML. Not XHTML, but that's not what we're talking about. You don't need to close `<input>` tags in HTML. And the second one is really just a matter of preference. The person could choose to not have a default value, and make it a required field. That's more accurate anyway, since users are forced to confirm the selection.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen—the first point is wrong, it results in invalid HTML and XHMLT. Input elements have no content and do not have closing tags in either HTML or XHTML. The correct XHMLT markup would be `<input ... />`. The second is also wrong - `document.forms[0].sex` returns a NodeList that has no *value* property, setting one radio button to checked doesn't fix that. It's also wrong because it suggests more invalid markup. The last point is also wrong because it doesn't identify the error that `document.forms[0].sex.value == 'female'` (i.e. `=` is changed to `==`) will always return false.